# What is stoicism and how to understand it

Tags: stoicism

I went through the word *stoic* recently and found that stoicism is a philosophy. I want to learn more about this stoicism. Can anyone refer me with some good material and help me in understanding more about stoicism?

Comment: Read Epictetus and Marcus Aurelius. Then ask again. Bill Clinton's view on [MA](https://www.nybooks.com/articles/1998/10/08/bill-the-emperor/) is well known

Comment: Thanks, Will read about them.

Comment: See John Sellars' [books on Stocism](https://www.google.com/search?sca_esv=5d48de1e8e0fb59b&rlz=1C1GCEB_enIT1093IT1093&q=sellars+stoicism&tbm=bks&source=lnms&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjumMa78raEAxWMhP0HHUnQAWIQ0pQJegQIYRAB&biw=1280&bih=593&dpr=1.5)

Answer (score 1):

You might like the ***Handbook of Epictetus***, which is a short introduction to the topic: https://classics.mit.edu/Epictetus/epicench.html.

Answer (score 0):

Philosophy Tube has a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lSvKNNtkUSU) on Stoicism that is a pretty good introduction to the topic. The [IEP](https://iep.utm.edu/stoicism/) and [SEP](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/stoicism/) also have articles on the subject.

It is also worth pointing out that English word 'stoic', when not capitalized, does not refer to the philosophical position of the Stoic philosophers. What happened was that as the millennium passed, the public understanding of what the Stoic philosopher's believed shifted, like a giant game of [Telephone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_whispers). Eventually, the difference became so great people started using capitalization to differentiate when they were using the plain-English word and when they were referring to the the specific philosophical movement. For example, a person who never expressed any emotions of any type would be stoic, but not a follower of the Stoic philosophy.